# What kind of antenna should i use for my esp8266 module?

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I have an esp8266 module and i want to increase its range by adding an antenna to it. What kind of antena should i use. Can i use an antenna from a RC car remote?[image]

Comment: 1) You need a 2.4GHz antenna. 2) There is no antenna connection on that module, so you will have to bodge it: https://www.instructables.com/id/External-Antenna-for-ESP8266/

Comment: An antenna from a RC car remote won't work? Can you send me a link of the antenna that you are talking about?

Comment: A 2,4GHz antenna is a 2.4GHz antenna. Antennae have to be a specific length and tuned to a specific frequency or they are next to useless (or worse, can *reduce* your range). If you can't be bothered to look for one in a shop using that simple search term, then rip one off an old dead WiFi router.

Comment: @Majenko im gonna rip off my old router's antenna. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use a WiFi (2.4 GHz) antenna. From the picture in your post, you have one of the esp8266 modules with a "built-in" antenna implemented via traces on the PCB. You cannot add an external antenna without removing the old one first, and even that will be very dodgy - you'll likely render your esp8266 useless for any purpose.

Instead, you could get an esp8266 that is made for connecting an external WiFi antenna. See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP8266) for details. It specifically mentions model # ESP-WROOM-02U as having a connector for an external antenna.